# Change text_field to dropdown (PP088)

Tags: php, html

Once again back with another question. I'm working on a project pier page for work. We want to have a place to put our projects so our manager decided we should take project pier and that I would have to just change it to our likings.

So far I'm getting there slowly, but I've run into a problem. There is a text field at a certain page where you need to enter a name. The thing is that this should be quick and the least typing possible.

So I've been digging through the code and found the form.

```
<?php echo text_field('project_form[name]', array_var($project_form_data, 'name'), array('id' => 'projectFormName', 'class' => 'long')) ?>
```

**That right there is the form. Now here is my question. Is there any way, that I can change that into a multiple choice dropdown box?**

Since it works with a database, it needs to enter this "name" to show up at a certain list on another page.

I was working on getting a dropdown, but to be honest.. I have no idea on how to implement it in such a way that it uses the form shown above to save it into the database so it can be used for the title on the next page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Edit-*

After trying a lot of things i came up with the next code:

```
`<select name="project_form[name]">
  <option value="<?php echo text_field('project_form[name]', array_var($project_form_data, 'name')) ?>"> - </option>
  <option value="<?php echo text_field('project_form[name]', array_var($project_form_data, 'name')) ?>">Idea</option>
  <option value="<?php echo text_field('project_form[name]', array_var($project_form_data, 'name'))?>">Initiation</option>
  <option value="<?php echo text_field('project_form[name]', array_var($project_form_data, 'name'))?>">Review</option>
  <option value="<?php echo text_field('project_form[name]', array_var($project_form_data, 'name'))?>">Planning</option>
  <option value="<?php echo text_field('project_form[name]', array_var($project_form_data, 'name'))?>">Execution</option>
  <option value="<?php echo text_field('project_form[name]', array_var($project_form_data, 'name'))?>">Acceptance</option>
  <option value="<?php echo text_field('project_form[name]', array_var($project_form_data, 'name'))?>">Production</option>
  <option value="<?php echo text_field('project_form[name]', array_var($project_form_data, 'name'))?>">Evaluation</option>
</select>`
```

This makes sure that the dropdown is seen as entering a name. Now I would just like some help with changing the outcome. As of yet the outcome is:

> input type=

So it generates a different result than wished for. Probably because I put the line into the value, but I'm not sure. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

So, after looking at it, trying and trying all the time. I finally found the way to do this. I changed the strings which I had put in value, and put them in a `name=""` So basically it now looks like

`<option value="Execution" name="<?php echo text_field('project_form[name]', array_var($project_form_data, 'name'))?>">Execution</option>`

Which posts the given option to the name field instead of the value. Therefore it now pulls the right information from the database.

I though i'd just post my answer in this post for future references. If in any case anyone would need it.